# Filter out records from parent class in a child class in Java

Tags: java, spring, wicket

How to filter out records from parent class in a child class in Java?  For instance, I have a parent class called `Company`, which will return all company records; I create a child class called `CompanyWithProduct` from "Company". The `CompanyWithProduct` class only returns company records that has product. I am using Spring Framework and Apache Wicket Framework to develop the application.

My child class looks like

```
public class CompanyWithProduct extends Company {

}
```

I am using LazyModel to get record from the child class. Here is the code:

```
private static final LazyModel<CompanyWithProduct> MODEL_COMPANY = model(from(CompanyWithProduct.class));
```

What kind of annotation should I use to implement the child class?

Answer (score 1):

it's more a question on OOP rather than on a particular framework. Instead of creating a subclass I would suggest to implement in class `Company` a `getRecords` method that returns every records and a `getRecordsWithProduct` that returns records with product.

my 2 cents.